# Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101 in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am using jQuery 1.7.2 and lighbox in my website.
The HTML code which I want to load in lightbox is following:

```
//script type="text/javascript">
//jquery code
</script>

//html code..
```

While using firefox and chrome there is no problem while opening lightbox,
but while using IE it is displaying following error:

> SCRIPT257: Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101. 
>   jquery.min.js, line 2 character 11497..

When I change script type from `text/javascript` to `text/html`, lightbox opens fine but now javascript code doesn't work...

Comment: could this help
http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9221

Comment: I was getting a similar error, upgraded to 1.8.3 and the error went away.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295207/could-not-complete-the-operation-due-to-error-80020101

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered this issue, as well.  I have been using `jQuery 1.7.2` and I am unable to get past this.

A solution was posted as being implemented in `jQ 1.8.2`, but that did not affect my results.

I changed my character encoding to UTF-8 (another suggestion I encountered), but that also did not help.

Eventually I rolled back to `jQ 1.4.2` (the next previous version stored locally) and the problem went away.  I know this isn't a "solution" but it's a workaround that got me back in the game and moving towards a deployable EAR.

Answer (score 0):

You have a Javascript code that can't be correctly evaluated. I had exactly the same scenario and the solution was to change the name of an associative array key from `class` to `"class"` (this is only one example of evaluation error).

For more details, please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903989/could-not-complete-the-operation-due-to-error-80020101-ie)