# Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

I am running an ExtJS 4.1 application. It is running just fine in FireFox, but I get this error in Internet Explorer 8: `Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101.`

I have found various possible fixes, but none seemed to fit my needs.

How can I make the application work in IE8?

Comment: @RobW I do not know where the problem lies. My application is pretty heavy on JavaScript(mainly because of the ExtJS framework) and the errors in IE8 are not helping at all. I have no idea on how should I find the source of the problem. I am hoping that someone else has faced this issue too(or anything similar).

Comment: Well, it can be narrowed down. 80020101 is an AJAX error, for example this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10275316/1204258

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thank you for the link! That was helpful: there was a comma after some ajax parameters, as suggested in that answer. Please write an answer so I can accept it(it wouldn't seem fair to write one myself, since it was your suggestion that helped).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Error 80020101 is an AJAX error, so there are a number of potential issues to investigate. A useful starting point might be a prior SO question https://stackoverflow.com/a/10275316/1204258 which deals with trailing commas in object definitions.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error in an included js file. it appeared only in IE.

the problem was because of missing `</script>` tag at the end of include file.

hope to help.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same non-foundable error on IE9.

There was an AJAX request transfering a ....

Solved the error with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    ... code goes here ...

    //]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Same thing was happening to me while using ExtJS to "require" modular javascript code. The reason: I included the "extends" keyword by mistake, which is reserved in IE8. Make sure you're not using any reserved keywords as your attribute keys without putting them in quotes first.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue in IE, the problem was the html comment used in the javascript
Replaced the html comment with javascript comment, then it's works fine for me.