# ng2-modal doesn't work in MS Edge

Tags: angular

I've used ng 2-modal. It works fine in chrome and IE but does not work in MS Edge. Does MS Edge usually gives such problems for angular 2..?
Used npm install ng2-modal --save to install packages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 not working with MS Edge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39540851/angular-2-not-working-with-ms-edge)

Comment: Please include more details like: what is the error message you receive, what behavior do you observe ("does not work" is short on details that would help discover a resolution), etc.

Comment: Actually it works fine with other controls. But while using ng2-modal it does not get some files. In other browsers it works fine. But in Edge it gives error 404 index.ts not found