# Angular2 not working on IE11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11

I have added es6shim as well but i'm getting above error on IE11 and the angular2 app is not working.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 not working with MS Edge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39540851/angular-2-not-working-with-ms-edge)

Comment: @Roy it says zone.js particularly in the error but this doesn't. I have installed the latest zone.js anyway still not working.

Comment: try to add in index under html tag <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular/angular/66df335998d097fa8fe46dec41f1183737332021/shims_for_IE.js" type="text/plain"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.5.9/es5-sham.js" type="text/plain"></script>

Comment: @YoavSchniederman the first html tag you provided is not found

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to **index.html**:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular/angular/66df335998d097fa8fe46dec41f1183737332021/shims_for_IE.js" type="text/plain"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.5.9/es5-sham.js" type="text/plain"></script>
```

Comment: it gives me the following error `SEC7112: Script from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular/angular/66df335998d097fa8fe46dec41f1183737332021/shims_for_IE.js was blocked due to mime type mismatch
localhost:3000`

Comment: ok,  if your client code is inside server code as java play you need to remove the security block

Comment: What do you mean??

Comment: Which server environment are you using ?

Comment: I didn't get you but i think it is webpack. This is front end so i'm confused??

Comment: just try only with the second script

Comment: are you using angular-cli/gulp/grunt ?

Comment: actually webpack it is gulp