# Error 80020101 on JQuery load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101. IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903989/could-not-complete-the-operation-due-to-error-80020101-ie)

I'm using JQuery 1.7.2 to load the content of a HTML file in a div. It works on every browser but I have a

```
`Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101`
```

error in IE7. How can I solve it?