# Error 80020101 on .val()

Tags: php, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101. IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903989/could-not-complete-the-operation-due-to-error-80020101-ie)

I'm facing a little problem with my jQuery code.

I have a first page with some fields like :
[Code 1] [Code 2] [Code 3]

The user type something in one of the input, I get the result that I load in another page with .load method. Here's the code :

```
$(function() {
    $("#code_cip").autocomplete({
            source: tab,
            minLength: 6,
            delay: 1000,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                        var selectedObj = ui.item;
                        $("#code_cip_ind").val(selectedObj.value);
                        $("#test").load("test.php?id="+selectedObj.value);
            }
        });
    });
```

This, works great. It correctly load the "test.php" page with the good values.
BUT... In the test.php page I have a form, and I try to fill it like this :

test.php :

```
<?php
    $gest_medecin = new gest_medecin($db);
    $medecin = $gest_medecin->returnValues();
    $adresse = $medecin->Adresse;
    echo $adresse // This, output the good value of the attribut
?>
<script>
    adresse = <?php echo $adresse;?>;
    alert(adresse);
    $("#adresse").val(adresse);
</script>
<input name="adresse" id="adresse" type="text" />
```

The problem is : 
When I try to alert the "adresse" var, or use it with my .val method, I get the error 80020101 in IE, and in Firefox, nothing is happening...

I tried to fill the variable with some test string like this :

```
adresse = <?php echo "123456" ?>
```

And that works great...
As mentioned I checked that the `$medecin->Adresse` was correct with my `echo` and it is. It contains something like "word1 word2"

I really have no clue why my code isn't working...

Any help ?

Comment: try `adresse = '<?php echo $adresse; ?>';`. Note the surrounding single quotes.

Comment: I bet you will see what the problem is when you have a look at the **generated** JavaScript code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always look at the final result to spot the error.

You are missing quotes around

```
    adresse = "<?php echo $adresse;?>";
```

strings always need quotes.

it worked with `123456` because that is an integer value that needs no quotes.

Firefox will tell you this in its error console with a better error message.

Comment: Oh gosh...
I really thank you for your answer.
After some coding nights, things are not so obvious for me apparently...

Thanks a lot ! (I'll accept your answer in 10 minutes :) )