# Could not complete the operation due to error 800a025e

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11, rangy

What does this error mean in IE10/11:

```
Error: Could not complete the operation due to error 800a025e.
```

And how would I debug it?

It says its this line:

```js
this.nativeSelection.removeAllRanges();
```

https://code.google.com/p/rangy/source/browse/trunk/src/js/core/wrappedselection.js#416

See it in action here: http://panmedia.github.io/raptor-editor/tests/cases/selection/selection-expand.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169786/clear-text-selection-with-javascript

Comment: An example would help.

Comment: I'm also getting the exact same error when calling `removeAllRanges()` in IE9, sporadically though. @TimDown I'm thinking of using your rangy library to see if the error goes away... but first I think I'll try http://stackoverflow.com/a/3171348/227299

Comment: Can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: @Dom I added an example link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22914075/javascript-error-800a025e-using-range-selector

Comment: @TimDown I added an example.

Answer (score 4):

I had this error coming up recently, I fixed it with the following chceck:

```
var sel = window.document.getSelection();
if (sel.rangeCount > 0 && sel.getRangeAt(0).getClientRects().length > 0) {
    sel.removeAllRanges();
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem using the trumbowyg html editor. Fixed it with this solution. Thanks

Comment: This started giving me another issue in chrome: "**Discontiguous selection is not supported**." where I use: `selection.addRange(range)`

Comment: I'd suggest to additionally use `window.getSelection().rangeCount` (for Chrome, but maybe also in other environments).

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when trying to `window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();` and there was no selection. One workaround is to check if there is a selection first:

```
if (window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).getClientRects().length > 0) {
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
}
```

Comment: You need to call `getClientRects`, the function itself will never have some length.

Answer (score -3):

All the error 80020101 means is that there was an error, of some sort, while evaluating JavaScript. If you load that JavaScript via Ajax, the evaluation process is particularly strict.

[Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101. IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903989/could-not-complete-the-operation-due-to-error-80020101-ie)

Comment: Indeed then when I run the code provided I was presented with 80020101