# IE 11 Error message - Could not complete the operation due to error 800a025e

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, exception, internet-explorer-11

I am getting the following error message in IE 11 : 
 **Could not complete the operation due to error 800a025e.**

This error is being thrown when range.select() is called

```js
  function ExtendSelection() {
      var sel;
      if (document.body.createTextRange) { // Internet Explorer
          var range = document.body.createTextRange();
          range.moveStart('character', 0);
          range.collapse(true);
          range.moveStart('character', 29); //causes an exception 
          //range.moveStart('character', 30);//No exception 
          range.moveEnd('character', 177);
          range.select();
          alert(range.text);
      } else {
          alert("Your browser does not support this example!");
      }
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="ExtendSelection ()">Click to reproduce the error</button>
<a >
    <span>
        <div>
            <select>                         
                <option>CopyTo:</option>
               <option>Headnote</option>
                <option>Synopsis</option>
                <option>Statute</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </span>
</a>
<a>
    <span>Pages: 8 - 8</span>
</a>
<a>
    <span>nortlaw</span>
</a>
<input>
```

Replicated for IE 11 browsers only ->[JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/1ytmj119/36/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22914075/javascript-error-800a025e-using-range-selector

Comment: I saw this post, but it was of no help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [Microsoft's documentation on TextRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535872%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it seems that the `collapse()` method doesn't exist. I removed that call, and the error went away.

```
function ExtendSelection() {
  var sel;
  if (document.body.createTextRange) { // Internet Explorer
      var range = document.body.createTextRange();
      range.moveStart('character', 0);
      // range.collapse(true); <-- IE does not understand this line
      range.moveStart('character', 29); //causes an exception 
      // range.moveStart('character', 30);//No exception 
      range.moveEnd('character', 177);
      range.select();
      alert(range.text);
  } else {
      alert("Your browser does not support this example!");
  }
}
```