# My Polymer website is completely broken on MS Edge

Tags: web, polymer, frontend, microsoft-edge, polymer-2.x

[My website](https://next.suttacentral.net) works fine on Chrome, Safari and Firefox, but for some reason is completely unusable on MS Edge. It freezes up, the styles are not being applied correctly, and the top bar jumps all over the place.

I have all the required Polyfills loaded.

Edit: [Here's](https://github.com/suttacentral/next-sc/tree/development/client) the source code.

Comment: Are you receiving any errors in your Edge console

Comment: After replacing it with `webcomponents-loader.js`, the page stops loading at an earlier stage, but displays an error in the console: "Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101". The error is coming from a dependency (`iron-icon`). [This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903989/could-not-complete-the-operation-due-to-error-80020101-ie) mentions a similar problem. In this case it was related to the JS comment style used, but I don't know what causes it in my project yet.

Comment: I just wanted to take a look but currently, this URL https://next.suttacentral.net/ is completely broken in Chrome (using v61) as well?

Comment: It's working great on the current versions of Chrome, Safari and Opera, this question is about MS Edge.

Comment: I know I just wanted to compare how it should look like and what it looks like in Edge... but at least for me, I can't as it's not looking nice on Chrome as well...

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problems in the past and never found out what exactly caused it. What I would advise you to test is replacing webcomponents-light
with webcomponents-loader.

```
<script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
```

Make sure that you empty the cache and maybe disable the service worker for testing.

Comment: I switched to `webcomponents-loader` and, while it seems to improve performance on Firefox, it did nothing for my Edge problems.