# JavaScript runtime error: Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-1.8

I am working on an asp.net mvc web application, and i have the following main view:-

```
<div class="box-content">


@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AssignCustomer", "Firewall", new AjaxOptions

{
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
    UpdateTargetId = "Customertable",
    LoadingElementId = "progress",
    HttpMethod= "POST",
    OnSuccess="submitform"





}))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.FirewallCustomer.ID)


<div>
<span class="f">Customer Name</span>


    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirewallCustomer.CustomerName, new { data_autocomplete_source = Url.Action("CustomerAutoComplete", "Firewall") })

  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirewallCustomer.CustomerName)




</div>


       <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary"/>
}
                        <p><img src="~/Content/Ajax-loader-bar.gif" class="loadingimage" id="progress" /></p>
<table  class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable">
 <thead>
<tr>
<th class="f"> Customer Name </th>


</tr></thead>
    <tbody id="Customertable">

    @foreach(var info in Model.Firewall.FirewallCustomers.OrderBy(a=>a.CustomerName)){
        <tr id= "@info.CustomerName">


<td> @Html.ActionLink(info.CustomerName, "Index", "Customer", new {searchTerm=info.CustomerName},null)</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>


         </table> </div></div></div>


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

which calls the following action method when submitting the Ajax.begin form:-

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [CheckUserPermissions(Action = "Edit", Model = "Firewall")]
        public ActionResult AssignCustomer([Bind(Include = "FirewallCustomer")] FirewallJoin fc)
        {
            fc.FirewallCustomer.CustomerName = fc.FirewallCustomer.CustomerName.Trim();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {

                    repository.InsertOrUpdateFirewallCustomer(fc.FirewallCustomer,ADusername);
                    repository.Save();

                    return View("_customerrow", fc.FirewallCustomer);
```

and the returned partial view from the action method call, (which should be inserted after the table body) looks as follow:-

```
@model TMS.Models.FirewallCustomer
<tr id="@Model.CustomerName.ToString()">
    <td>@Model.CustomerName</td>



    <td>
        @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete",
 "DeleteCustomerFirewall", "Firewall",
new { firewallid = Model.ID, customername = Model.CustomerName},

new AjaxOptions
{ Confirm = "Are You sure You want to delete " + Model.CustomerName,
    HttpMethod = "Post",

    OnSuccess = "deletionconfirmation",
    OnFailure = "deletionerror"
})

    </td>
    </tr>
```

now when i click on the ajax.beginform insdie my main view the record will be added to the DB, but the partial view will not returned , instead i will get the folloiwng exception :-

```
   0x80020101 - JavaScript runtime error: Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101.
```

And the the jquery 1.8.2 will throw an exception (throw e) on the following code:-

```
if ( !transport ) {
            done( -1, "No Transport" );
        } else {
            jqXHR.readyState = 1;
            // Send global event
            if ( fireGlobals ) {
                globalEventContext.trigger( "ajaxSend", [ jqXHR, s ] );
            }
            // Timeout
            if ( s.async && s.timeout > 0 ) {
                timeoutTimer = setTimeout( function(){
                    jqXHR.abort( "timeout" );
                }, s.timeout );
            }

            try {
                state = 1;
                transport.send( requestHeaders, done );
            } catch (e) {
                // Propagate exception as error if not done
                if ( state < 2 ) {
                    done( -1, e );
                // Simply rethrow otherwise
                } else {
                    throw e;
                }
            }
```

Can anyone adivce what is causing this problem ?

Comment: Do you have any custom Javascript code (not the jQuery library itself) on your page? If yes, then please check it for some "unexpected content", like extra commas in object literals or HTML comments inside script code etc. BETTER: Show us the code :-)

Comment: this views share the same custom scripts as the other pages , and these custom scripts are working fine on the rest of the application.

Comment: Ok, but this is a Javascript error ... and I bet the problem is not within the jQuery library

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ajax request problem: error 80020101](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918969/ajax-request-problem-error-80020101)

Answer (score 2):

All the error 80020101 means is that there was an error, of some sort, while evaluating JavaScript. If you load that JavaScript via Ajax, the evaluation process is particularly strict.

Sometimes removing // will fix the issue, but the inverse is not true... the issue is not always caused by //.

Look at the exact JavaScript being returned by your Ajax call and look for any issues in that script. For more details see a great writeup here

http://mattwhite.me/blog/2010/4/21/tracking-down-error-80020101-in-internet-exploder.html

Comment: can you advice what do u mean by removing  // ??

Comment: In developer tool check what data is being returnedd by the ajax call. There must be something that is breaking your full javascript code.