# IE9 - Error 80020101 after div injection of a web app in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, internet-explorer-9, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've done an injection of a web application (in Angular) through `jQuery` load and sometimes i receive this error:

> Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101.

When evaluates js in Internet Explorer 9 with document mode set to IE9.

I've done a research and I've read that one reason are probably html comments, I've clean all libraries and html from comments but Angular generates html comments when using `ng-repeat`.

Is it another problem?

Is it possible to avoid this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918969/ajax-request-problem-error-80020101

Comment: Thanks. I'll try some of these advice.