# SCRIPT1003: Expected ':' in IE11

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-11

After cleaning up my code, getting this error - SCRIPT1003: Expected ':'

```
 globalEval: function( data ) {
        if ( data && core_rnotwhite.test( data ) ) {
            // We use execScript on Internet Explorer
            // We use an anonymous function so that context is window
            // rather than jQuery in Firefox
            ( window.execScript || function( data ) {  //***ERROR LINE
                window[ "eval" ].call( window, data );
            } )( data );
        }
    },
```

Comment: ...use a jQuery version that supports IE11.

Comment: `jQuery.globalEval()` is compatible with IE 11 and the root cause is not in this function. Error 80020101 is an AJAX error and there are a number of potential issues to investigate. You could refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918969/ajax-request-problem-error-80020101/10275316#10275316) for potential issues. If it still can't solve your problem, I suggest you to provide [a minimal code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can reproduce the issue so that we can have a test.

Comment: @YuZhou I did try the solutions you suggested, ended up with a new error. Edited my post accordingly. Will try to add-in sample code.

Comment: @Tomalak i would upgrade the jquery version if i could...but i have to stick with this

Comment: You don't have to upgrade it, you have to downgrade it. jQuery dropped support for IE 11 at some point. Consult their compatibility matrix and use a compatible version.

Comment: (Of course the other consideration is that the `data` you are trying to execute as a script has an error of its own.)

Comment: Hi @JenniferFernandes , how about the sample code? We need a reproducible code to provide further help.